# including language in paginator links

Tags: cakephp

I have a multilingual site and I am trying to use the paginator. However the pages navigation never includes the language (just the controller and action are included)

```
<?php
 echo $paginator->first(' << ', null, null, null);
 echo $paginator->prev(' < ', null, null, null);
 echo $paginator->numbers();
 echo $paginator->next(' >', null, null, null);
 echo $paginator->last(' >> ', null, null, null);
?>
```

Example:　URL - http://dev.cyclistsroadmap.com/eng/segments/

Current: http://dev.cyclistsroadmap.com/main/segments/page:5

should be http://dev.cyclistsroadmap.com/eng/main/segments/page:5

Comment: Do the languages work okay regardless of the pagination url?
Are you using the i18n component?

Comment: yes. e.g. http://dev.cyclistsroadmap.com/jpn/segments/

Comment: It seems to work okay. Is there a reason you want the language to appear in the URL?

Comment: so that both languages appear in search results.

The languages themselves work fine. I just can't get the language into the pagination urls

Comment: Implemented temporary workaround. 

class AppHelper extends Helper {

 function url($url = null, $full = false) {

  $urlReturn = parent::url($url, $full);

  if(isset($this->params['lang'])) {
  $urlReturn = '/' . $this->params['lang'] . $urlReturn;

  }     
  return $urlReturn;
 }
}

But its pretty messy, I would like to get this done right.

Comment: -1 Clever way of "bumping" a question.

Comment: Wasn't a bump. (I didn't even think it would bump). Could you please remove the -1

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/view/advanced-pagination-1-2) out. You can set extra parameters with paginate->options.

```
<?php
$paginator->options(array('url'=>array('lang'=>'eng')));
?>
```

Then add in your routes.php file like this. Then if you add the parameter in the options (as in the live above) then it should work as you want.

```
Router::connect('/:lang/:controller/:action/*', array(), array('lang' => 'eng/', 'property' => '[0-9]+'));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I had already seen and tried that. That gives me

http://dev.cyclistsroadmap.com/main/segments/page:5/lang:eng

Comment: As far I can see you managed to do it :) Or at least the pagination have the proper lang variable

Comment: As I wrote above, I implemeted a hack to get the job done in the meantime. I still want to do it right in the end.

Comment: paullb - check my answer again, I've modified it.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I got this to work was to hack the paginator library to add the lanuage. (unfortunate that cakephp made this so inflexible)